# Understanding how to bind a JSON string into a list of objects in C#?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to convert a string into a list of objects in C#. I've written the following:

My input string is something of the following:

```
[{"channelID":"15","thresh":"30"},{"channelID":"28","thresh":"14"}]
```

I'm doing the convering using `json.net`

```
var deserializedResultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TriggerDataList>(result);
```

Now this is where I start to get hazy. I attempted the following class properties to no avail.

```
class TriggerDataList
{
    [JsonProperty("Triggers")]
    public List<TriggerData> Triggers { get; set; }
}

class TriggerData
{
    public string channelID { get; set; }
    public string thresh { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to bind that result to a List of TriggerData objects?

Comment: For reference, you can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to check what kind of class would best suit your json data (Your classes are correct though). For your case (from the sample provided) there is no "Triggers: ..." so you could just try `var deserializedResultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TriggerData>>(result);`.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I'm getting NonInvokable Member list cannot be used as a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I tried your code on a clean solution, I will post exactly what I did as an answer rather than comment:

```
string json = "[{ \"channelID\":\"15\",\"thresh\":\"30\"},{ \"channelID\":\"28\",\"thresh\":\"14\"}]";
List<TriggerData> deserializedResultList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TriggerData>>(json);
```

And the class (remember to make it **public**):

```
public class TriggerData
{
    public string channelID { get; set; }
    public string thresh { get; set; }
}
```

The above json (escaped for C#) worked and gave me 2 `TriggerData` objects in a list.

Comment: Perfect, had a typo :) This is exactly what I want.

Comment: Glad I could help, even if it was just a typo :)